# Is it possible to use Metal and SceneKit at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

All the tutorials that I've found online speak about using Metal alone, without any other supporting library. But I don't understand if it's possible to create a SceneKit game and then use a Metal layer just to make some optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

Yup! As of iOS 9, you can set a SceneKit SCNView to use a Metal renderer on devices that support it by initializing it with the `SCNPreferredRenderingAPIKey` key in the options dictionary, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/View_Initialization_Options). Something along these lines should work:

```
let sceneView = SCNView(frame: someFrame, options:[SCNPreferredRenderingAPIKey: NSNumber(unsignedInteger: SCNRenderingAPI.Metal)])
```

That’s pretty much all you need to do; the way you interact with the rest of the API remains unchanged.